# Javascript - Closing confirmation message if no response from user

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have got asp.net 2.0 website, in which I display session timeout through confirm message box, asking user to select ok or cancel.

Problem: if user doesn't provide any input (assuming his desktop is locked and he is out for lunch) - then how can I close this confirmation message and display another pop-up or re-driect to login page

Regards

Comment: Why do you want to do this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the native browser confirmation box you cannot dismiss that, the user would need to do so.  If you create your own, then you can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to dismiss after a certain amount of time

Comment: yes im using native browser confirmation box, how can we create our own?

Comment: These kinds of UI elements are called modals. If you can use jquery there is the dialog UI element which works pretty well. http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

As haslama suggested that you will have to create a custom alert as you can't dismiss the browser confirmation box.

As an alternative you can show a div based message to user instead of an alert, and in that div user can select OK or cancel and you can implement timeout for that div.