# How to create a prompt with multiple input in plain javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a modal dialog like prompt() method. How can i make a prompt dialog with 2 input like this one :

[image: sample]

with plain javascript (without using any jquery/javascript framework).

Is it possible to create such prompt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are native browser-specific controls that you cannot modify. Also for alert, prompt, and confirm, you may only supply values to them. Please see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177109/javascript-closing-confirmation-message-if-no-response-from-user/12177256#12177256)

Answer (score 0):

for a modal prompt, my suggestion is:

1. create a screen filling div to get the modal result:

   ```
      <div id="modalDiv" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%;
      height: 100%; z-index: 4; display: none">&#160;</div>
   ```
2. create a div for the prompt, with a higher z-index and with the text fields, labels, buttons and everything you need. Have it centered on the screen.
3. make a function customPrompt (or whatever name you like) in which you set the display of both divs to "block" and to the OK button set a function that handles the input for whatever you need.